# How to memoize a react function for older inputs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, memoization, react-fullstack

I want this component to not calculate square callback on every click of button. Instead it should store previously calculated value and return. I understand that `useMemo` only caches the result of last render and not across multiple renders with different `props/states`. I want to know if I can achieve true caching using react constructs.

```
const App = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(2);

  const MemoizedSquare = useMemo(() => {
    console.count("calculating square");
    return num * num;
  }, [num]);

  const handleButtonClick = useCallback(() => {
    setNum((prevNum) => (prevNum === 2 ? 9 : 2));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {MemoizedSquare}
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>toggle label</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Store them in a ref, or simply outside of the component